# SAS Count array

Tags: sas

Say I have a data 'test1' that has a variable 'student_name' and English_score on it. I need to get the count of the number of students who scored more than 50 marks in 'English' from this data set. There are similar 
data sets like test2, test 3, test 4 etc that also has got variable 'student_name'. I would like to get the counts on the students from these data sets as well who scored more than 50 to see the trend. 
I am not able to use the array since I used a SQL statement. Is there a better way to do this? Here is my code.

```
    data Sample1;
    set test1;
    run;
    PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE Work.Student AS 
    SELECT distinct s1.student_name, 
    FROM Work.sample1 s1
    WHERE s1.English_score > 50;
    QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the code by removing data step that does nothing except rewriting test1 to sample1.
You can simply query the test1 table

with SQL:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE Work.Student AS 
SELECT distinct s1.student_name, 
FROM Work.test1 s1
WHERE s1.English_score > 50;
QUIT;
```

or with data step:

```
data work.student;
set work.test1(where=(english_score gt 50));
run;
```

Do a test and see which one is faster.